Smooth transition between separate models
I have modelled a face where I have kept the eyelids their own separate objects, so I can easily animate them by just rotating them. You can see I have rotated the eyelids a little bit between the two pictures below.


However, the transitions along the yellow edge in the bottom picture is harsh - is there a way to smooth that transition while keeping the objects separate? Maybe using a shader? I plan on exporting the model to Unity when it is done, so I am looking for a solution that also works in Unity.
Any help or suggestions are welcome!

You can get a decent result with this method, though I won't fight anyone over possible better solutions. I'm also unsure about how well this will transfer to external apps like Unity. I know that a shader would have to be a 100% Unity option as you can't really transfer shaders between apps usually.


Start with modeling a thin strip of polys with at least 3 concentric edge loops, one in the middle and the others that will sit on the eye lids and face respectively.

Try to manually line up the topology to sit comfortably on where it should lie, middle loop in the crease between eye and face, etc. Add a little extra geo and split the corners at the tearducts.

Then add two vertex groups, assigning the outer loop to the face group, inner to the eye group and all of the in-between loops to both groups at .5 strength.

Then add 4 modifiers, two Shrinkwrap and two Data Transfer, one each assigned to either vertex group. I used these settings:


I also added a SubSurf mod before all of this, which helps smooth things out generally, but might not be available in your workflow.
The full stack:

The end result, there are a few janky spots that might need tweaking but I think its the best you can do without modeling out a full eyelid that connects to the face itself. You could also probably get rid of a bit of the jank by actually rigging the shrinkwrapped verts to the eyelids themselves with vertex weights, so that the animation is actually moving the verts, not solely relying on the Shrinkwrap mod to move them.

From a distance it's fairly imperceptible.

